# An Immediate RSS Reader

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, rss

Does anyone knows a RSS reader that checks updates constantly, or at least each 10 seconds or so? (Maybe 30 seconds…)

The maximum rate Mail checks RSS is 30 minutes, which is ridiculous. It's not an overwhelming work to check a RSS feed. The feed I want to subscribe is not continuously updating, but when it updates, it's crucial to know what's new instantly.

Comment: It's not overwhelming for you, no, but if *everyone* hit every 10 seconds the bandwidth would be insane. You might want to check out google reader. The advantage of a huge web-based service is that they can check a lot and distribute the results within themselves - not check once per user - so their update times are very fast.

Comment: Not at least NetNewsWire (30 minutes), Vienna (5 minutes) or Reeder (5 minutes). NNW has an option for *Use custom refresh schedule* per feed, but the minimum value is 1h.

Comment: If you need that kind of immediacy, you should be looking for a way to get the information via a connection-oriented method (e.g., IRC, other IM protocols, ssh into the server, etc.) rather than banging their door down by polling more frequently. Let them tell you when there's something new instead of saying, "Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we there yet? Are we..."

Comment: To compliment @DaveSherohman's comment, [Inezha](http://en.inezha.com/) is an RSS to IM bot which can read(not sync though) your Google Reader subscriptions

Comment: @Phoshi: I agree that polling a feed every 10 seconds is crazy. However, assuming the client uses HTTP If-Modified-Since, the traffic would be approx. 2-5 MB per day if there weren't any updates during that time. (Not enough to melt a server.) If combined with a central polling server (for multiple clients to read the same feed), this would actually be doable.

Comment: @grawity; Even if no real content is transferred, there's still the issue of having, assuming you have a decent amount of people trying to poll your feed, several hits a second *on top of* regular browsing hits. A lot of weaker servers couldn't take that.

Answer (score 1):

None exist right now, for the reasons explained well by @Phoshi.  One advantage of Google Reader is its support for [PubSubHubbub (PuSH)](http://code.google.com/p/pubsubhubbub/), allowing instant (non-polled) updates when subscribed to a feed that uses it.  [Most major blogging platforms do](http://www.quora.com/What-websites-provide-a-pubsubhubbub-feed).  Consider asking your favorite RSS client authors to support PuSH as well.